# Java BufferedReader only reads once

Tags: java, networking, bufferedreader

I'm writing a server that parses opcodes (just a simple little hobby MMO server to teach myself the ropes; it's a little messy at the moment) and I'm having trouble having the server parse a second opcode. I'm not sure what the issue is. The format of each opcode is an 8-byte header such as PRINTMSG and then the body, which in this case could be a message such as Hello. Each opcode is terminated with a '|'. My code seems to be getting and parsing each opcode correctly, but it's not executing anything past the first one, which leads me to believe there is something I don't understand about BufferedReaders. I'm reading it using read(), and storing each character in a 48-byte array. Autoflushing is set to true.

Here is the relevant server code:

```
public String readInputStream() {
    String msg = "";
    char[] charArray = new char[48];
    short i = 0;
    char current = '#';
    int characterInt = -1;

    while (current != '|') {
        try {
            if (in.ready()) {
                characterInt = in.read();
                if (characterInt == (-1)) continue;
                current = (char) characterInt;
                if (current == '|') break;
                charArray[i] = current;
                //if ((charArray[i] == 'n') && (charArray[i-1] == '\\')) {
                //  charArray = new char[48];
                //}

                i++;
            }

        }


        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading input stream in server ConnectionThread");
            if (DEBUGMODE) System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    msg = new String(charArray);
    msg = msg.substring(0,i);
    return msg;
}
public static void printMsg(String msg) {
    System.out.println("(Op-PRINTMSG): " +msg+"\n");
}



public static void executeOpCode(String op, String body) {
        if (op.equals("ABSPLAYX")) receivedPlayerAbsoluteX(body);
        else if (op.equals("ABSPLAYY")) receivedPlayerAbsoluteY(body);
        else if (op.equals("FIRSTVOL")) requestVolley();
        else if (op.equals("SECNDVOL")) returnVolley(body);
        else if (op.equals("PRINTMSG")) printMsg(body);

    }
```

And the main loop:

```
public void run() {

    while (shouldBeListening) {
        //Main loop for the connection thread
        String op = readInputStream();
        //If stream has data, add the opcodes to opQueue.
        if (op != ("")) {
            separateOpsFromStream(op, incomingOpQueue);
        }

        //Extract incoming opcode head and body, then execute.
        //This executes everything in the queue before moving on.
        while (incomingOpQueue.size() > 0) {

            op = incomingOpQueue.poll();
            if (op != "") {
                String opHeader = OpCodeOperations.readHeader(op);
                String opBody = OpCodeOperations.readBody(op);
                playerData.executeOpCode(opHeader, opBody);
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Also, unless you're really trying to learn about how to create your own serialization format, I'd recommend at the very least using DataInputStream, or better, a more feature-rich serialization library.

Comment: Are you by any chance recreating reader object on each iteration?

Comment: 1. If you're processing bytes you should be using an input stream, not a reader. 2. get rid of the ready() test. You should be blocking in the read() method, not smoking the CPU. 3. There is no auto flushing on a reader: the relevance of this remark escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mark and reset the reader?

```
 bufferedReader.mark(0);
 bufferedReader.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not fully understand your problem, but here is my advice. Have you tried to modify the message? Every message has to end with "/n", or rather EOL mark. Could it be that?

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
if (op != "")
```

to:

```
if (!op.isEmpty())
```